# Cannot convert type 'mshtml.IHTMLElement' to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement'

Tags: c#

I have to parse following code and obtain only the number

```
<li><strong>Voltage:</strong>99.35614</li>
```

Now I saw that using HtmlElement I can have NextSibling (IHTMLElement doesn't) that contains my number. Since the text have no TAG I have no idea how to get without using regular trimming functions.

```
IHTMLElement ss2;
((HtmlElement)ss2).NextSibling.InnerText
```

The problem is that I cannot cast from IHTMLElement to HtmlElement
I even tried ss2.document and exception appears.

Cannot convert type 'mshtml.IHTMLElement' to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement'

Any clues? Thanks in advance

Ok, I found'it, casting to IHTMLDOMNode worked

```
((IHTMLDOMNode)ss2).nextSibling.nodeValue
```

Thanks all,

Comment: try to see what Type ss2 is by calling .GetType()

Comment: ss2.GetType() {Name = "HTMLPhraseElementClass" FullName = "mshtml.HTMLPhraseElementClass"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}

Comment: which implies that it is not HtmlElement

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to parse the HTML?

Comment: I really don't understand why give negative votes while I struggle all day to find something, than share with others. Quite ugly.

Comment: @user1797147 You are allowed to answer your own question and accept is answered also.

Comment: @user1797147 It's basic debugging. For basic debugging questions it is hard to tell whether you just did not bother investigating yourself, or whether you lack the knowledge of how to debug (and would benefit from having that explained). The former is bad, the latter is not, and we cannot tell from your question which is the case. (Note: I did not and will not vote.)